# PostAsJsonAsync adding leading character to request body

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have strange problem when trying to use PostAsJsonAsync. 
In body I get this json with strange leading and trailing characters:

> 99   {
>
> "SessionReferenceId":"f39dc178-279e-4e3a-bda9-a16829eb0e45",
>
> "GameReferenceId":"netent_es_starburst",
>
> "CurrencyCode":"EUR",
>
> "LossLimit":100,
>
> "ClientType":1
>
> }
>
> 0

and on API side this can't be binded and I get Error message that the request cannot have empty body.

Code on the sending side is like this:

```
using(var client = new SGSClient()) {
  var model = new CashSessionCreateModel()
            {
             ClientType = ClientType.DesktopBrowser,
             CurrencyCode = "EUR",
             GameReferenceId = "netent_es_starburst",
             LossLimit = 100,
             SessionReferenceId = "f39dc178-279e-4e3a-bda9-a16829eb0e45"
           };

 HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, model).Result;
}
```

Adding HTTPClient configuration:

```
public SGSHttpClient()
        {
            var appSettingsFilePath = $"Configuration\\appSettings.json";

            // Build Configuration
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(appSettingsFilePath, false, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var sgsConfig = configuration.GetSection("SGSClient");

            //Base url for SGS service
            var _clientConfig = sgsConfig.GetSection("Client").GetChildren();
            var baseAddress = _clientConfig.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Key.Equals("BaseAddress"));
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress.Value);

            //Adding headers
            DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            _dateUTC = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u");
            DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DateUtc", _dateUTC);


        }
```

Comment: "weird characters" type issues in general tend to point to encoding mismatch, but I'm struggling to think of what would cause these particular ones to appear. What is the target service running on?

Comment: @TomW .Net Core 2.2

Comment: Can you include the `HttpClient` configuration / initialization code?

Comment: @scheien I've updated the question with additional code,

Comment: Have you inspected the request/response with Fiddler to see if there are anything there related to encoding / content-type?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's missing the charset, I switched to PostAsync and StringContent where I can set the charset. But it realy boders me that I can't use this AsJson method, because the model binding is not working properly on api side.
If you could post some answer so I can accept it. Thanks also thanks to @TomW

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and [one other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67533477/c-sharp-httpclient-postasjsonasync-adds-a-strange-character-to-the-body) were the only useful pages I found when I was scratching my head over this same issue today. Neither question had satisfactory explanations though. So after some more head scratching, I was able to set my mind at ease. Hopefully [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70931216/326110) on the other question explains the behavior to your satisfaction!

tl;dr

`PostAsJsonAsync` uses `JsonContent` which uses `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` instead of `Content-Length` and the "strange characters" are chunk headers (and perfectly valid HTTP/1.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type format to send may be helpfull

```
 var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<ClassNameOfObject>(baseUri + "ControllerName/ActionName?UserID=" + UserID, object);
                postTask.Wait();
```

Comment: what is the difference?