# C# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync adds a strange character to the body

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-5

i have an application in .NET 5, I'm trying to call an API with HttpClient using method PostAsJsonAsync, like this:

```
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IgnoreNullValues = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("subjects", userRegistrationRequest, jsonSerializerOptions);
```

but I obtain always status code 500, so I tried to inspect the body request with fiddler and I noticed strange chars at the start and at the end of the body, like this:

```html
5F
{
  "id": "82240631-8c12-4b77-8626-7d36f93ceacc",
  "language": "en",
  "type": "subject"
}
0
```

But if I use classic PostAsync like this:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("subjects", new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(userRegistrationRequest, jsonSerializerOptions), 
            Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json));
```

the body is correct:

```html
{
  "id": "82837dba-c86d-4cf2-9c98-7f402b2761a1",
  "language": "en",
  "type": "subject"
}
```

and it works fine. Why does this happen?
Thank you.

Comment: To be sure: `JsonContent.Create` creates the same body, with 5F and 0?

Comment: [(`PostAsJsonAsync` uses `JsonContent`)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c73ef4965d397c57ca1ef37435fc9cfc818773d3/src/libraries/System.Net.Http.Json/src/System/Net/Http/Json/HttpClientJsonExtensions.Post.cs).

Answer (score 5):

As Stephen pointed out in the comment, `PostAsJsonAsync` uses `JsonContent`. `JsonContent` uses `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` (instead of setting Content-Length; See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding)), so it can stream the data.

The `5F` in your request is hex for 95, specifying that the upcoming chunk of the content is 95 characters long. The `0` indicates that the upcoming (zero-length) chunk is the terminating chunk, and thus the end of the content.

This is all totally valid HTTP/1.1. It's likely that whatever server is responding with 500 is just not correctly implementing HTTP.

As you pointed out, a workaround is to create your own StringContent, which won't use chunked transfer encoding, and will instead set the `Content-Length` header, which is more likely to be accepted by weak HTTP implementations