# Using PostAsJsonAsync in an Azure Function doesn't send the body. Works in WebAPI for .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.http.json

When using a http client in an azure function (.Net 6), the body is null when received.

Here is what is called:

```
await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, value);
```

If I do the same thing in a web api (same code in .Net 6), it works.  Following the reference in `PostAsJsonAsync`, the function points to `HttpClientExtensions` in `System.Net.Http`, and the web api references `HttpClientJsonExtensions` in `System.Net.Http.Json`.

If I add the following to the function:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
```

It still uses `HttpClientExtensions` in `System.Net.Http`.

The only way I could get it to work in a function is by explicitly calling the `static` class:

```
await HttpClientJsonExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync(_httpClient, uri, value);
```

Would this be the only way to use this for a function?  Why does the web api `HttpClient` use the `System.Net.Http.Json`, but the function needs to pass in the `HttpClient` as a parameter to `PostAsJsonAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

> It still uses `HttpClientExtensions` in `System.Net.Http`.

- In place of `System.Net.Http`, you have to use the reference of `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` for using the `HttpClient`

> but the function needs to pass in the `HttpClient` as a parameter to `PostAsJsonAsync`.

- There are few methods given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-6.0) regarding how `HttpClient` is passed as a parameter to the `PostAsJsonAsync` but you can use `PostAsync` call with the above new `dll` referencing.
- As one of the similar issues registered on the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/374#issuecomment-879056747) of Azure Functions Dotnet - body is null when using `HttpClient` in the `PostAsJsonSync` Method/call, thanks to @*waynedavisactivu's* workaround:

```cs
var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/wh/link", content);

///Azure Function HttpRequestData.Body contains data
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and also assumed the Request Body was being sent null or empty.

My Error was "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.".

I used Fiddler and determined that I was indeed sending JSON in the request body. However, there was what looked like some extra encoding around it. So the reason I had my error was because the Azure Function was trying to those extra characters as JSON.

I found another post that helps showcase the issue I saw.
[C# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync adds a strange character to the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67533477/c-sharp-httpclient-postasjsonasync-adds-a-strange-character-to-the-body)

From what I can tell there is nothing you can do from the HttpClient side. That post states "This is all totally valid HTTP/1.1. It's likely that whatever server is responding with 500 is just not correctly implementing HTTP.". This would imply that Azure Functions are not correctly implementing HTTP or there is a configuration issue.